# Javascript convert string to binary with a fixed length

Tags: javascript, binary, append, converters

Is there an ***elegant*** way to convert some string to binary and get a result with a fixed length?
The built-in function is: `parseInt(str, 10).toString(2)`, but it's cutting the length.

For example, if I want length = 8 bits, then `myFunction("25")` will return `00011001` instead of just `11001`.

I know that I can append zeros to the beginning, but it doesn't seems like an elegant way to me.

Comment: Why not? what's wrong with padding with zeroes explicitly? `if (str.length < 8) str += Array(8 - str.length + 1).join("0")` doesn't seem too bad, and you can always encapsulate it within a helper function if it's occurs repeatedly.

Comment: Think about it. If you were to write such a function, at the end of it you'd be padding zeroes. Just a fact of life. Nothing non-elegant about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the most elegant way to do that is to write (or get somewhere) missing abstractions and compose them to achieve desired result.

```js
// lodash has this function
function padStart(string, length, char) {
  //  can be done via loop too:
  //    while (length-- > 0) {
  //      string = char + string;
  //    }
  //  return string;
  return length > 0 ?
    padStart(char + string, --length, char) :
    string;
}

function numToString(num, radix, length = num.length) {
  const numString = num.toString(radix);
  return numString.length === length ?
    numString :
    padStart(numString, length - numString.length, "0")
}

console.log(numToString(parseInt("25", 10), 2, 8));
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern JavaScript:

```
const number = 25;

number.toString(2).padStart(8, '0');  // '00011001'
```